# Jmeter_ Response Error Like :http response code: 405 Method not allowed

Tags: jmeter

when i am trying to upload the image in the web application using POST method of HTTP using Jmeter ,Its throwing error as below

**Sampler Request:**

```
Size in bytes: 436
Headers size in bytes: 335
Body size in bytes: 101
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 405
Response message: Method Not Allowed

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE
Content-Length: 101
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Set-Cookie: ARRAffinity=a1634f39ccba9517317254d32be7078bb62c2877a947d85cab990f2708382045;Path=/;Domain=revflexsit.azurewebsites.net
Date: Tue, 28 Jun 2016 10:04:41 GMT


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html
DataEncoding: null
```

**Request:**

```
POST http://revflexsit.azurewebsites.net/#//testerprofile

POST data:
--8WPDqrXY5glD81_9CcLHn-xfOTrWvH4Dh4srjx
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="profileUploadPhoto"; filename="Tulips.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

<actual file content, not shown here>
--8WPDqrXY5glD81_9CcLHn-xfOTrWvH4Dh4srjx--


[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 621121
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=8WPDqrXY5glD81_9CcLHn-xfOTrWvH4Dh4srjx; charset=US-ASCII
Host: revflexsit.azurewebsites.net
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.2 (Java/1.8.0_40)
```

**Response Data:**

```
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) is being used.
```

Answer (score 2):

The server response is pretty much self-explanatory, you're not allowed to make POST requests to that URL, only GET, HEAD, OPTION and TRACE ones.

Why just not to record your test scenario using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) and modify the resulting test "skeleton" as required?

If you are still eager to build your scenario manually,looking into the  http://revflexsit.azurewebsites.net/ site, it seems correct request will look something like:

- Path: `/api/TesterProfile/UploadTesterProfile?Id=${YOUR_ID_HERE}&UpdateAdminId=0&dimensions=x,y,x,y`
- Files Upload:

  - File Path: full path to image, you're trying to upload
  - Parameter Name: `profileUploadPhoto`
  - MIME Type: relevant photo [MIME Type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME)

Don't forget to tick "Use multipart/form-data for POST" box.

See [How to Test Image Upload Functionality With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-test-image-upload-functionality-jmeter) for more detailed explanation.